# Getting value of generator function, koa

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, koa

I have a function that pulls out from database a random question from Questions collection.

**Game_Questions.js** - console.log below prints out correct value (string I need), so I thought that return will let yield give me back same value.

```
exports.random_Question = function *() {
   yield Questions.findRandom().limit(1).exec(function(err,question){
     console.log("rand q: " + question[0].text);
     return question[0].text;
   });
}
```

**Game.js:**

```
var Game_Questions = require('./backend/Game_Questions');
```

And here I want to access `question[0].text` value from `random_Question` function from code snippet above (Game_Questions.js). What I've tried so far:

`var found_Question = Game_Questions.random_Question();`

`var found_Question = Game_Questions.random_Question().next().value;`

Those two return [Object object] which after using JSON.stringify() shows that the object is:
`{"value":{"emitter":{"domain":null,"_events":{}},"emitted":{},"ended":true},"done":false}`

I also tried using `co(function*())` but it also didn't let me take out the value. Please help how to access it?

Comment: You will always need to use a callback, because it's asynchronous. `co(Game_Questions())` should return a promise for the value iirc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by @remus is a callback approach and Koa was designed explicitly to ditch callbacks. So while it's perfectly good code and would fit an Express application it is completely at odds with the design philosophy behind Koa.

From the looks of it you are using Mongoose which has supported promises for async operations since version 4.0 (which was released Apr 2015) which should allow a yield approach to be taken. Note I'm making an assumption you are working with Mongoose - I hope I'm not wrong!

[Here is some nice documentation on how Mongoose would fit nicely with koa.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/harmony.html)

So first of all make sure you are using a version of Mongoose that supports using yield. If not you'll have to use the @remus approach or manually wrap each of your methods so they are yield compatible (i.e. wrapping with promises).

But if you are using a compatible version (4.0 and upwards) then your code would look something like the following:

```
exports.random_Question = function *() {
  var result;

  try {
    result = yield Questions.findRandom().limit(1).exec();
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e.stack);
    throw e;
  }

  console.log("rand q: " + result[0].text);
  return result[0].text;
}
```

Note that I'm assuming the result is an array based on the code you supplied.

The above example doesn't necessarily have to be a generator function. It could also be a normal function that returns a Promise. So alternatively something like this could also be done:

```
exports.random_Question = function() {
  return Questions.findRandom()
    .limit(1)
    .exec()
    .then(function() {
      // I'm assuming mongoose assigns the value
      // being resolved in exec() to 'this'
      var question = this[0];
      console.log("rand q: " + question.text);
      return question.text;
    }).catch(function(e) {
      console.log(e.stack);
      throw e;
    });
}
```

So for the `randomQuestion` function all that is important is that it can be yielded by `co` which handles the Koa application flow control – check [tj/co on GitHub](https://github.com/tj/co) for the different objects you can yield.

So finally getting back to the Koa Middleware we can `yield` either of the above code snippets in the exact same manner. So we'd do:

```
var koa = require("koa");
var app = module.exports = koa();
var Game_Questions = require('./backend/Game_Questions');

app.use(function*() {
  var resultText;

  try {
      resultText = yield Game_Questions.random_Question();
  } catch(e) {
    this.throw(500);
  }

  this.body = resultText;
  this.status = 200;
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Something else to note is that I'm a little unsure of the `findRandom` method in the mongoose query since I don't know if it plays nicely with the Promise features of mongoose. Personally I'd get a normal mongoose query working using `yield` before reintroducing `findRandom` just to make sure it's not causing an issue.

My answer is getting a bit long at this point so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Hi @Peadar Doyle, you're right, I'm running Mongoose in my project and it's 4.0.7 version so it should support yield. And the reason I was using `questions[0].text` as a result was because `questions` was a mongoose array of objects, and I wanted value of "text", so I figured out I can access it that way. I tried your solution, but I'm not sure how should I call this function in my other file. `Game_Questions.random_Question().next().value;`  and `var Game_Questions.random_Question();` don't work unfortunately

Comment: I've updated my answer. Understanding how `co`, `generators`, and `promises` work within Koa is the toughest challenge to learning it. Unfortunately these also provide all the advantages of Koa as well; so you can't gloss over them.

Comment: Thanks for very informative answer. I can see the problem I'm facing right now - my example (Game.js file) is just a snippet from whole method, which contains many standard (not-generator) functions. I understand that I should have made them in koa standards so I wouldn't be facing this problem now. I'll try to rewrite my functions and I'll update you with result. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm impressed, it really worked. Both answers are correct but yours is obviously better because of koa-style and using generators. Thanks a lot. If anyone is interested you can [check the diff on github here](https://github.com/jwitos/takismieszny/commit/84db3719ccee44f3c6d16ab778de31f456be7992).

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is pretty strange, but not sure if that's specific to Koa or not?

Because Node.js is event based, use a callback instead:

```
exports.random_Question = function(callback) {
    Questions.findRandom().limit(1).exec(function(err, question){
        callback(err, question);
    });
}
```

And use it:

```
var Game_Questions = require('./backend/Game_Questions');
Game_Questions.random_Question(function(err, question) {
    console.log(question);
});
```

Of some concern as well is your question states you're trying to reference `Game_Questions.randomQuestion()` when your function is actually named `random_Question`.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot @remus, I made terrible syntax error so yes, there should be random_Question **but** it gives me back `[Object object]`. When I try your solution, _questionText_ is undefined, probably because console.log runs before `random_Question()`.

Comment: if `question[0].text` doesn't exist, that would account for undefined. What happens when you log `question` inside the callback function of `findRandom()`?

Comment: Then it logs correct value - both in your solution and my example with generator function. @remus

Comment: Wow, you're great! :) It worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. And sorry for my strange syntax, still working on the basics.